# How to add d3 in html

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am beginner in D3 and I want to add right after the table a simple line chart in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

            <table id="personsTab"> 
            <tr>
                <th id="name"><span>Name</span></th>
                <th id="birth"><span>Birth</span></th>
                <th id="death"><span>Death</span></th>
            </tr>   
            </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have found this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/T546B/) and dont know how to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to follow these tutorials [Aligned Left](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/fundamentals) they cover the basics like setup and such and some simpler forms of charts